# WP7 custom namespaces and prefixes

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I came across this webpage about how to have cleaner namespaces in silverlight 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/xaml_custom_namespaces.aspx

Anybody know if this works for WP7 too?

When I try it I get an message that "Type or namespace name 'myclassname' could not be found"

This is what I have in my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
//Map all Namespaces in the project to the IQ prefix  
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.myapp.com/wp7/", "iq")]  
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.myapp.com/wp7/", "MyApp.Controls")]
```

And in my page:

```
xmlns:iq="http://schemas.myapp.com/wp7/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Mapping a C# namespace to a string (typically a URI) for your own assemblies is a [Silverlight 4 feature](http://blogs.profitbase.com/tsenn/?cat=19). Silverlight for WP7 is based on Silverlight 3, hence this feature is most likely absent.

Comment: It should however become available as part of the "Mango" update.